# Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

> Hello, I am facing the titled error when I try to update password. The problem I'm facing in laravel 8 framework. In case of update password I need to catch the old hashed password that is saved in the database. So, I tried in belows way, but facing this error.

auth.php below

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],


    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Confirmation Timeout
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

];

Admin Controller method

```
    public function UpdatePassword(Request $request)
{

     $request->validate([
        'old_password' => 'required',
        'new_password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

     if(!Hash::check($request->old_password, auth()->admin()->password)){
        return back()->with("error", "Old Password Doesn't match!");
    }
     
    // $hashedPassword = Auth::Admin()->password;
    // if(Hash::check($request->old_password, $hashedPassword)){
    //     $admin = Admin::find(Auth::id());
    //     $admin->password = Hash::make($request->new_password);
    //     $admin->save();
    //     Auth::Logout();
    //     return redirect('admin')->with('status', 'Password Changed Successfully!');
    // }
    // else{
    //     return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something Wrong!');
    // }
    // return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Password Changed Successfully!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `admin()` doesnt exist in the Auth classes. Use the guard admin and the method `user()`

```
if(!Hash::check($request->old_password, auth('admin')->user()->password)){
```

```
auth('admin')->user()
//will return an instance of the model of the "admin" guard. in this case App\Models\Admin::class
```

Comment: This is a custom model Named Admin and I need to check old_pass with the admin table. note that there is a admin table in the database @N69S

Comment: @MD.RONYAHMED yeah, you still use the method `user()` with the guard "admin". if you prefer, use `auth()->guard('admin')->user()->password`

Comment: used but not worked.. same error

Comment: @MD.RONYAHMED did you run at least once `php artisan config clear` after you changed the auth files ?

Comment: yes, basically can you clear that where I will use  auth('admin')->user(); ??

Comment: @MD.RONYAHMED when you login an admin, you dont use `auth()->attempt($credentials)` but use `auth('admin')->attempt($credentials)` or `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)`. The logged in user in session will be of the guard "admin". to recover that admin from session, you need to use `auth('admin')->user()`